# Route Sound From Programs Into DAW (Windows)

Tags: daw

I'm wondering if there are (free) programs that can take an audio signal from a program (and only that program) and route it as a virtual audio input into my DAW. For example, I might want to send audio from a DJ program into the DAW on Track 1, then connect a mic on Track 2 and mix both tracks together. It should also preferably stop the sound from the DJ program from going directly to the soundcard out, and route it to the DAW instead.

Please not that the program has to be free, and I also don't want to use the "stereo mix" option on my soundcard since that will make a big mess (the audio goes through the DAW, through VST filters, and then out throught the soundcard)

If there are alternatives to this (aside from using 2 computers) also let me know.

Comment: -1: Please don't write shopping questions. http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-do-you-think-about-shopping-recommendations

Answer (score 4):

- [JACK Audio](http://jackaudio.org) will do this on Linux, OSX and Windows.
- [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/) is similar, but only works on OSX.
- [Rewire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReWire) must be explicitly supported by all applications involved in the audio routing process.

Comment: Good question, but I haven't used Windows for audio work in over a decade. You should add this clarification to your question.

Comment: I'm not trying to convince you to change your platform, just noting that I really don't know anything about audio on Windows. Let's try to stay on-topic.

Comment: 'Doesn't look as difficult' - are you serious?

Comment: that explains why there are so many answers to this question!